# Ant - build script does not find pathelement defined in a properties file

Tags: java, ant, build

I have an ant build script that has the following targets:

```
<target name="_initLiveProps">
        <property file="buildscripts/live.properties"/>
</target>

<target name="buildLive"  depends="_initLiveProps">
        <property file="buildscripts/live.properties"/>
</target>
```

Within the build script i have several pathelements declared as shown below:

```
<path id="project.class.path">      
        <pathelement location="./../lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar" />
        <pathelement location="${product-def.jar}"/>
</path>
```

The product-def.jar definition is defined in the buildscripts/live.properties file as

```
product-def.jar=./../lib/product-def/live/product-def.jar
```

When i build the project (using ant buildLive) i get compilation errors and mainly because it cannot find classes defined within product-def.jar.

I tried to print out the classpath as shown below

```
<property name="myclasspath" refid="project.class.path"/>
<echo message="${myclasspath}" />
```

And the output comes out as `c:\product\lib\log4j-1.2.16.jar;c:\product\${product-def.jar}`

The above suggests that the following definition is not correct

```
<pathelement location="${product-def.jar}"/>
```

What is the correct way of defining a path element that is defined in a properties file?

### Edit

I think the issue is that the definition for project.class.path is initialised before the properties file is loaded in the buildLive target. 
Is there a way to delay the initialisation of project.class.path until after buildLive target has completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to delay the initialisation of project.class.path until after buildLive target has completed?

Put the `<path>` definition inside the `<target>`

```
<target name="_initLiveProps">
        <property file="buildscripts/live.properties"/>
        <path id="project.class.path">      
                <pathelement location="./../lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar" />
                <pathelement location="${product-def.jar}"/>
        </path>
</target>
```

The `<path>` will be visible to all targets that depend (directly or indirectly) on this one.

If you have several different targets that load different properties, e.g. `_initLiveProps`, `_initDevProps`, etc. then you could put the `<path>` definition into a common target as follows

```
<target name="classpath">
        <path id="project.class.path">      
                <pathelement location="./../lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar" />
                <pathelement location="${product-def.jar}"/>
        </path>
</target>

<target name="_loadLiveProps">
        <property file="buildscripts/live.properties"/>
</target>
<target name="_initLiveProps" depends="_loadLiveProps, classpath" />

<target name="_loadDevProps">
        <property file="buildscripts/dev.properties"/>
</target>
<target name="_initDevProps" depends="_loadDevProps, classpath" />
```

Comment: Yes this will probably work but i have so many targets that depend on the path and i cant really put the <path> definition on each one of them. Maybe i can create a new target that each of them depend on .

Comment: @ziggy that's what I meant - put the `<path>` definition in the same target that loads the properties file, which presumably all the targets that require the path will already depend on.

Comment: What i meant is that there are other targets which do not depend on the _initLiveProps target. For example the target for loading the development properties does not depend on this target which loaded the live properties file.

Comment: @ziggy I see what you mean now.  I've edited my answer with a possible way to do this- you need to rename your existing `_init...` targets to something else and then declare a new target that depends on the old `_init...` _followed by_ the target that creates the `<path>`.  Just having the existing `_init...` depend on the classpath target won't work because it'll do things in the wrong order.