# When are Ant path references set?

Tags: java, ant, build

When I use a path reference ID, Ant seems to evaluate any variables inside the definition before any tasks run.  For example, `${common.dist}` and `${common.lib}` below seem to be  evaluated before any tasks run.

```
<path id="compile.classpath">
      <fileset dir="lib">
         <include name="*.jar" />
      </fileset>
      <fileset dir="${common.dist}">
         <include name="*.jar" />
      </fileset>
      <fileset dir="${common.lib}">
         <include name="*.jar" />
      </fileset>
</path>
```

In the Ant output I see something like this:

```
Adding reference: compile.classpath
Property "common.dist" has not been set
Property "common.lib" has not been set
...
Build sequence for target(s) `package' is [...]
Complete build sequence is [...]
```

This makes it seem like the path reference is being processed before any targets are run.

I have a compile target like this:

```
  <target name="compile" depends="init,common">
    <javac destdir="build/classes" debug="true" deprecation="true" optimize="true">
      <src path="src/java" />
      <classpath>
        <path refid="compile.classpath" />
      </classpath>
    </javac>
  </target>
```

If I copy the guts of the path reference into the classpath element inside the compile target, things seem to work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any tasks outside a target are executed on every build, in order of appearance in the `build.xml`, before any targets are run.  If you want to use properties in a `<path>` defined outside a target then you need to put the `<property>` task that defines the properties also outside a target, and before the `<path>`.  If you need to load the properties within a target then you'll have to put the `<path>` definition inside a target too (either the same one or one that runs after the one defining the properties).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15788306/592139) (and my answer) for more details.

Comment: Thanks.  I moved the property definitions out of the target and above the path definition and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the [Ant manual - path like structures](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#path):

> **By default a path like structure will re-evaluate all nested resource
>   collections whenever it is used**, which may lead to unnecessary
>   re-scanning of the filesystem ...

I think you maybe forgot to set the ${common.dist} and ${common.lib} properties. They should be outside any target:

```
<property name="common.dist" location="dist"/>
<property name="common.lib" location="lib"/>
```